# JHipster - Removing # HASH from URL permanently

Tags: java, jhipster

I can see all the urls in jhipster are having #, how to remove it properly, I don't want to show # in my application's urls,  I created application in angular 4

Comment: Angular 1 or 4? Be prepared for some work on java side also, it's not that easy at least if you're a beginner.

Comment: I created jhipster application 4.6.2 and angular js 4

Comment: OK then try it by yourself, in angular edit `layout-routing.module.ts` and change `useHash: true` to `useHash: false`  and then for java here is a start https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4794#issuecomment-304097246 because the issue is now that deep linking  requires server to distinguish between URLs that should be handled by client or by server.

Comment: See this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253124/jhipster-react-remove-to-url/54461348#54461348 <= See this post

Comment: See this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253124/jhipster-react-remove-to-url/54461348#54461348 the correct for Jhipster + React

Answer (score 0):

We do have this tip in our docs although I have never tried it myself :
https://jhipster.github.io/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html
The tip is only for angularjs 1. You can try to combine it's advice with the official angular docs on routing : https://angular.io/guide/router

If you manage to make it work please do a PR on our website : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours to achieve this and finally has paid off. You can follow these steps:

1. Remove on angular app avery use of hash location strategy in every RouterModule.forRoot...:

   `{useHash: false}`
2. Go to java app to the config folder and create a new java class to manage the error pages to redirect to `index.html`:

```
@Configuration    
public class ErrorPageConfig implements ErrorPageRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerErrorPages(ErrorPageRegistry registry) {
        registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html"));
    }
}
```

This page was very helpful
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-angular

Comment: Note that this will return 404 responses for your pages even though it displays them, which I'm guessing is not good for SEO